# Iterate function over a list

Tags: python, loops, python-3.7, literate-programming

I have a list in which total number of items may change. I want to apply a function which requires two inputs on first two items in the list and with the result I want to apply the same function on the third item in the list and with the result I want to apply function for fourth and so on...

Is there a better way to do the below when you know number of items in the list

```
for x,y,a,b,c...n in result:
    z=np.convolve(x,y)
    z=np.convolve(z,a)
    z=np.convolve(z,b)
    z=np.convolve(z,c)
    .
    .
    .
    final=np.convolve(z,n)
print(final)
```

Comment: That's just `reduce(np.convolve, result)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is called reduce-function. Python [has them](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce).

For your case, you can use them like this:

```
from functools import reduce

reduce(lambda x, y: np.convolve(x, y), result)
```

Comment: Upvoted, but note that you should always include an initializer value for the reduce function, including here.

Comment: No, it is optional. In the case of OP's question the behaviour is exactly equal to his expectations: `If the optional initializer is present, it is placed before the items of the sequence in the calculation, and serves as a default when the sequence is empty. If initializer is not given and sequence contains only one item, the first item is returned.`

Comment: Great, but how does this handle an empty list? You can get away with leaving out an initializer _sometimes_, but providing one makes for clearer code and, importantly, keeps you from breaking out of your monoid.

Comment: In the case of the empty iterator it will crash. But does OP has empty iterator? Anyway, we don't know what he has in the `result`.

Comment: The length is variable, per the OP. No reason to think it's always non-zero length.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
for args in result:
    x, y, *others = args
    z = np.convolve(x,y)

    for a in others:
        z = np.convolve(z,a)
```

Comment: No. Use reduce, don't reimplement it yourself.

Comment: Yes. It may not be elegant, but it's not worth two instantaneous downvotes, IMHO.